# Sum of a well-ordered sequence of ordinals

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

The sum of a well-ordered sequence of ordinals is defined recursively:

1. $\sum_{i \in \alpha} x_i = 0$ if $\alpha = 0$,
2. $\sum_{i \in \alpha} x_i = \left(\sum_{i \in \beta} x_i \right) + x_\beta$ if $\alpha = \beta + 1$,
3. $\sum_{i \in \alpha} x_i = \sup_{\beta \in \alpha} \sum_{i \in \beta} x_i$ if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

This definition has likely been known for more than a century, and yet, I have not been able to find it in print. Does anyone know of a good reference for it? A widely circulated textbook would be the ideal reference for me.

Comment: Maybe Rosenstein's *Linear orderings*?

Comment: Or Sierpinski: Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers.

Comment: Noah, François, thanks for your help!

Comment: You can also look at Hausdorff's work (which has been translated into English), but I'll have to comeback for a more precise reference.

Comment: It could also be defined explicitly as the ordertype of the lexicographic ordering on $\{ (i,j) : i < \alpha, j<x_i \}$.

Comment: Definition 1.38 (p. 19) of Rosenstein's book.